# how do I take input for an array and print it?

Tags: c#

```
int i, c; string b;
Console.WriteLine("enter no of elements");
c = Console.Read();
string[] s = new string[c];
for (i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("enter elements");
    b = Console.ReadLine();
    s[i] = b;
}
Console.WriteLine("Array : ");
Console.WriteLine("[{0}]", string.Join(", ", s));
//Console.Write(s);
```

I am trying to take inputs for an array and print the same but instead its producing an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer points out, the input is being treated as ASCII

Try changing this line

```
c = Console.Read();
```

to this

```
c = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to be careful, when you do:

```
c = Console.Read();
```

and you type 5 then the value of c is not 5 but 53... cos you are not reading an int

remember 5 as ascii is mapped to 53 in integer